# Domain Admins can't connect to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, permissions, connectivity

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 domain controller and a database server (W2K12R2/SQL Server 2012).

As allowed usergroup I have given the group "domain-admins" *sysadmin* rights.

But somehow any domain-administrator can't connect to that SQL Server, but when I add the domain-administrator user directly as allowed user it does work.
The active directory does work. RDP-Login works. Am I missing something?

Does anybody know how to grant access to the whole group "domain-admins"?

The error message is:

```
Servername: SRV-DB
Error Number: 18456
Schweregrad: 14
Status: 1
Line of Code: 65536
```

In the event log it says (translated):

> Error checking the token based server access with infrastructure failure.

State is "1" . I log on to that db-server with RDP as an domain-admin. I have to explicitly start SSMS with "run as administrator". Then I can access the "localhost". If I leave out starting SSMS as admin then I can't do that. I thought being in the group "domain-admins" would be enough.

Comment: And the state number? 11? See https://sqlblog.org/2020/07/28/troubleshooting-error-18456

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13821289) by Remus Rusanu.

As an domain-admin connected to that SQL-Server-Host via Remote Desktop. I had to start SQL Server Management Studio explicitly "as an administrator". (right-click -> run as administrator).

If SSMS isn't started in administrator mode, the current login is not in "builtin\administrators"-group. That was the problem.

It comes from Windows user access control (UAC). So that is actually a security "feature".

Comment: Ok, so it was exactly what state 11 suggests [in the link I posted earlier](https://sqlblog.org/2020/07/28/troubleshooting-error-18456).

Comment: That's not a "feature", it's exactly how [UAC is supposed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/jj574202(v=ws.11)) to work:  `With UAC, applications and tasks always run in the security context of a non-administrator account, unless an administrator specifically authorizes administrator-level access to the system.`

Answer (score -2):

It's easy.
If you are able to Logon with old credentials ( the Administrator of local computer ) you have to use it to access a Remote Desktop and use it to add the Domain Controller Administrator